# LG Web OS cannot open internal link

Tags: javascript, html, webos, enyo, lg

currently, i'm developing LG Smart TV apps using HTML5, css and javascript and i dont use **Enyo Framework**. Everything fine on local browser.

But when i deploy to my **LG WebOS Emulator** (.ipk file) using LG SDK CLI, i cannot open Internal Link (**browser.html**).

my question is why i cannot open internal link on my index.html?
below is part of index.html code :

```
<a href="browser.html">Browser </a>
```

The Error Messages : "***Network Error (7), Network is not connected. Please check network settings***."

I'm expecting my apps can open **browser.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 day research, I found the solution. I changed the **appinfo.json** file

**before:**

```
{
"id": "com.cirova.app1",
"version": "1.0.2",
"vendor": "cirova",
"type": "web",
"main": "index.html",
"title": " My Apps",
"icon": "icon.png",
"largeIcon": "largeIcon.png",
"uiRevision":2,
"enyoVersion": "2.5",
"onDeviceSource": {
    "enyo": "$enyo-framework/2.5/enyo",
    "lib/layout": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/layout",
    "lib/moonstone": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/moonstone",
    "lib/spotlight": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/spotlight",
    "lib/enyo-ilib": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/enyo-ilib",
    "lib/enyo-cordova": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/enyo-cordova",
    "lib/enyo-webos": "$enyo-framework/2.5/lib/enyo-webos"
}
```

Remove all dependencies library path to **Enyo Framework**

**after:**

```
{
"id": "com.cirova.app1",
"version": "1.0.2",
"uiRevision": 2,
"vendor": "Cirova",
"type": "web",
"main": "index.html",
"title": "My Apps",
"appDescription": "My Apps",
"icon": "icon.png",
"largeIcon": "largeIcon.png",
"iconColor": "blue",
"bgColor": "white",
"splashBackground": "app_bg_1920x1080.png",
"bgImage": "app_bg2_1920x1080.png"
```

}

After above changes, I can go to another html files easily...

Error explanation : Network error means LG WebOS cannot find the files, because they are missing in config...